# Part of list item's text aligned left and rest aligned right

Tags: html, css, html-lists, text-align

I would like to have part of `<li>` content aligned to the left ("Title") and rest of it ("[button]") to the right. For each item.

I'm using following `HTML` code:

```
<ul class="dual-align-list">

    <li><div>Title</div><div>[button]</div></li>

    <li><div>Title</div><div>[button]</div></li>

</ul>
```

and styles:

```
ul.dual-align-list li
{
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
}

ul.dual-align-list li div:first-child {float: left}

ul.dual-align-list li div:nth-child(2) {float: right}
```

But I have a bad feeling, that I'm doing something really wrong.

Is there a better approach/solution to this problem?

Comment: Your code works > [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z6VdY/). What is the issue?

Comment: @3rror404 Yes, I know it works! :] Have you noticed last two lines: "_But I have a bad feeling, that I'm doing something really wrong. Is there a better approach/solution to this problem?_". I'm trying make myself sure, that it not only works, but it is also semantically OK and follows modern standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I have a bad feeling, that I'm doing something really wrong.
>   Is there a better approach/solution to this problem?

The only problem is your classes and use of pseudo-elements aren't very semantic. A better approach would be to give classes to your `div`s that describe what their content is, and style them that way.

```
<ul class="title-content-list">
    <li><div class="title">Title</div><div class="content">[button]</div></li>
</ul>
```

And CSS

```
ul.title-content-list > li { display: block; height: 25px; }
ul.title-content-list > li > div.title { float: left }
ul.title-content-list > li > div.content { float: right }
```

Or something along those lines.

It's **very** bad practice to use "left" or "right" as class names - what if you later decide you want your title on the right and button on the left? You'd have to change all your HTML, or have weird CSS where `.right` positions elements on the left and `.left` on the right.

Comment: Joshua, I'm **not** using `left` and `right` as class names! This comes from NuclearApe's answer above, not from my question! :] For me this is as obvious as for you. BTW: the idea of classes instead of pseudo-elements sounds interesting, thanks!

Comment: `...It's very bad practice to use "left" or "right"` Really? Bootstrap and it's rabid followers would disagree. Bootstrap includes the well used classes `pull-left` and `pull-right`. Not using the class name `left` because of a developers inability to find replace class names in their source code isn't a valid reason to not use them. It is actually bad practice to give numerous elements their own individual class names instead of using reusable class names like `pull-left` and `pull-right`.

Comment: It doesn't matter what Bootstrap does, it matters whether class names and elements are semantic or not and giving a `div` the class "right" is absolutely not. Bootstrap can do whatever it likes, it doesn't make what they do good practice.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing seems to be working (at least per how you describe what you are looking for here). I'm assuming that your issue is the complexity of your selectors? If so, one thing you could try is moving the selector to the individual element. I know for bootstrap they call this pull-right so I went ahead and did that:

```
<ul class="dual-align-list">
    <!-- Title really only needs to be in a div if you
         plan on styling it further -->
    <li> Title <div class="pull-right">[button]</div></li>
    <li> Title <div class="pull-right">[button]</div></li>
</ul>
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGxWy/) for a working example with that in it. Hopefully this addresses the actual question!

**Edit**

By the way, if the issue is just how far the button goes to the right you can put everything in a fixed width container or you can add a margin-right to the "pull-right" class. For the fixed width container, just wrap your ul in:

```
<div class="container"> <!-- "ul" here --> </div>
```

You will also need the following style rule as well:

```
/* edited to use percents for a responsive layout */
.container { margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5% }
```

I put this in an update to the previous fiddle [you can find here](http://jsfiddle.net/EGxWy/2/). Hopefully that helps some as well. Good luck!

**EDIT (2)**

Changed fixed width layout to responsive layout with 5% margins. These could be adjusted per the desired result or even styled with the @media element to vary based on screen size!

Comment: Thanks for the idea with unnecessary `<div>` for title (indeed, no styling required) and for making JsFiddle. As for your edit -- no. This goes to a fluid-like theme, so no fixed width allowed. Thanks again!

Comment: Even with fixed width you can still style in percents if you need a margin. I'll update accordingly

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dual-align-list">
    <li>
        <div class="left">Title</div>
        <div class="right">[button]</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="left">Title</div>
        <div class="right">[button]</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.dual-align-list li {
    display: block;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
ul.dual-align-list li .left {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
}
ul.dual-align-list li .right {
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: In which way your code is better than mine? Except for this, that you're using an absolute positioning, which is very bad idea, AFAIK